# how to find partition of record oracle

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, database-partitioning

I have a table and there is a partition on it.

There are 16 hash partition which is starting from SUBSCRIBER_01 .. etc

Table name: SUBSCRIBER

Partition Column: CUSTOMER_ID (VARCHAR2 10)

Database : 11g

How can I find partition of a record?

Like Customer_ID=933587

Answer (score 20):

Select the rowid for the row, and the `DBMS_RowID.RowID_Object()` procedure will extract the data object id.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_rowid.htm#i997153

Look up that data object id in the data dictionary and read the subobject_name.

For example:

```
   SELECT dbms_rowid.rowid_object(ROWID) data_object_id
   FROM INVOICE
   WHERE INVOICE_ID = 2268041139:

   -- data_object_id = 546512

   select * from user_objects where data_object_id = 546512;

   -- SUBOBJECT_NAME = 'PART_P2099_P00'     
   -- OBJECT_TYPE = TABLE PARTITION
   -- OBJECT_ID = 464826
   -- DATA_OBJECT_ID = 546512
```

Answer (score 2):

You can using this script:

```
SELECT L.*, O.SUBOBJECT_NAME
FROM 
  (
    SELECT DBMS_ROWID.ROWID_OBJECT(ROWID) DATA_OBJECT_ID, L.*
    FROM YOUR_TABLE L
    --WHERE L.ID = 123
  ) L
  JOIN 
  (
    SELECT SUBOBJECT_NAME, DATA_OBJECT_ID 
    FROM USER_OBJECTS
  ) O ON O.DATA_OBJECT_ID = L.DATA_OBJECT_ID
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can only find the partition name where cust_id = 123... allocated:

```
SELECT partition_name, tablespace_name
 FROM user_tab_partitions
WHERE table_name = your_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
select distinct SUBOBJECT_NAME from user_objects where data_object_id = (SELECT distinct dbms_rowid.rowid_object(ROWID) data_object_id FROM <your table name>   WHERE <your partition key> = <partition key value>and rownum=1)
```

I am using hash partitioning here.

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer.

```
 DECLARE
       pi_partition varchar2(50);
       v_sql        varchar2(250);
       i            number;
       sy          number;
    BEGIN
       FOR i IN 1..16
       LOOP
          IF i < 10 THEN
            pi_partition:= 'SUBSCRIBER_0'||i;
          ELSE
            pi_partition:= 'SUBSCRIBER_'||i;
          END IF;

          sy:=0;
          v_sql:= 'select count(*) into :say from subscriber partition('||pi_partition||') where customer_ID='||''''||'933564'||'''';
          --dbms_output.put_line(pi_partition);
          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql INTO sa;


          IF sy > 0 THEN

            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Result: ' || sy||pi_partition);
            EXIT;
          END IF;
       END LOOP;
    END;
```